# numberFormat object loses value when converted to a string

Tags: java

I'm curious why converting to a string loses the decimal but when I pass in the object directly it maintains it's value.

```
//set number of decimals at 1 

//This code produces whole numbers even though I set number to 1 decimal point.
NumberFormat number = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
number.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);
String averageScoreString = number.format(averageScore);
String message = "Average score is: " + averageScoreString

//This code appears to produce the correct number format.
NumberFormat number = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
number.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);
String message = "Average score is: " + number.format(averageScore);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`setMinimumFractionDigits(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMinimumFractionDigits%28int%29) (which controls the *minimum* displayed number of digits), *and* [`setMaximumFractionDigits(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMaximumFractionDigits%28int%29) (which controls the *maximum* number of displayed digits) -

```
int averageScore = 10;
NumberFormat number = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
number.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
number.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);
String message = "Average score is: " + number.format((double) averageScore);
System.out.println(message);
```

Output is

```
10.0
```

and this produces the same output

```
NumberFormat number = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
number.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
number.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);
String averageScoreString = number.format(averageScore);
String message = "Average score is: " + averageScoreString;
System.out.println(message);
```

**Since**, you want it to not *lose* the decimal. And, I assume you always want one (and only one) decimal place.

Comment: I didnt get how his code prints 2 different results

Comment: @eldjon It didn't *except* when testing `int` vs `double` and say `10` vs `3.3` (or an *integral* `double` like `10.0` vs `3.3`). At least that's what I inferred.